# How can I add custom keys to to mongoose schema item?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a simple *mongoose schema* for a post:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false
    }
})
```

And I would like to add a custom key to each item called *interface*, that I could later use in a automatically generated post creation page.

**Like this**

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        interface: '<input type="text" name="title">'
    },
    
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false
        interface: '<textarea name="body">...</textarea>'
    }
})
```

But after creating a post with this *schema* and accesing this is the result.

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6151f2bbf678e03c1b2f609c"),
  title: 'a post',
  body: 'body...',
  __v: 0
}
```

How do I acceses the interface key of each property? like: `post.title.interface`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it on the Post class and not on its instances; `Post.schema.paths.title.options.interface`.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the line that's causing your error we can see that JS thinkgs you're trying to assign multiple strings with a random unknown keyword in between.
`interface: "<input type="text" name="title">"`

Those double quotes come in pairs, using a double quote will open a string that's then closed by the next double quote. The simplest fix is to wrap the whole string inside on single quotes like so.
`interface: '"<input type="text" name="title">"'`